# How to read and update rows of a Google Fusion Table using JAVA code

Tags: java, json, google-fusion-tables, geonames

(Edit: This is a question that I had and I answer it in the hopes of helping someone else who had a similar question.)

I am trying to clean up geographic data in my Google Fusion Table and would like to write a Java program to read in select Fusion Table rows, modify columns in each row and write out the modified rows back to the original fusion table.

I have found Christian Junk's example code in the Google API Client Libraries documentation: ["fusiontables-cmdline-sample"](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/fusiontables/v2) that shows how to: Authorize access to a users fusion tables, list tables, create a table, insert data into a table, show rows, delete a table.

How do I modify this example to make updates to selected rows in a table? (see answer with code below)

[edit]: I didn't find any good solutions on the Net. I have written the solution in Java and will answer in the answers in the hope that it can help someone else how is trying to do this. I am a novice Java programmer so the code reflects that. I also needed to get nearby big cities based on a gps location and used [GeoNames api (citiesJSON)](http://www.geonames.org/export/JSON-webservices.html) creating a bounding box to do that. This solution uses JSON to access items returned from REST calls.

Comment: I don't get why I am getting downvoted for trying to help others with the same question. That sucks! I guess that no good deed goes unpunished!

Answer (score 0):

I have written a Java program that does the row data modification described in the question. It uses [Christian Junk's example](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/fusiontables/v2) noted in the question and also calls [GeoNames citiesJSON webservice](http://www.geonames.org/export/JSON-webservices.html) as described in the question (sending bounding box coordinates in the parameters). I'm a novice in Java so the code is what it is. I do a lot of commenting in order to reuse code, like SQL queries, later.

You can find my solution on Github at: [FusionTableModifyJava](https://github.com/gjkendall/FusionTableModifyJava)
The primary module of interest is: [FusionTableSample.java](https://github.com/gjkendall/FusionTableModifyJava/blob/master/FusionTableTest02/src/main/java/FusionTableSample.java)
Here are the functions that do the getRows and updateRows. Everything else can be seen at github (by Microsoft$):

```
private static void getRows(String tableId) throws IOException {
    View.header("Updating Rows From Table");
    /*Sql sql = fusiontables.query().sql("SELECT RowID, 'Area Name', Notes, Number FROM " + tableId +
            " Where Manager = '' AND 'Review 1' CONTAINS IGNORING CASE '.fs.' Order by Number ASC LIMIT 3000");*/
    /*Sql sql = fusiontables.query().sql("SELECT RowID, 'Area Name', Notes, Number FROM " + tableId +
            " Where 'Area Name' CONTAINS IGNORING CASE 'Tioga George' Order by Number ASC LIMIT 3000");*/
    /*Sql sql = fusiontables.query().sql("SELECT RowID, 'Area Name', Notes, Number FROM " + tableId +
            " Where 'Area Name' ='' Order by Number DESC LIMIT 2000");*/
    /*Sql sql = fusiontables.query().sql("SELECT RowID, 'Area Name', Notes, Number FROM " + tableId +
            " Where 'Area Name' CONTAINS 'X01' Order by Number DESC LIMIT 1"); */
    /*AND 'City (nearest)' DOES NOT CONTAIN IGNORING CASE 'Mexico'*/

    /*Sql sql = fusiontables.query().sql("SELECT RowID, 'Area Name', Notes, Number, Location FROM " + tableId +
            " Where State = '' Order by Number DESC LIMIT 100");*/
    /*Sql sql = fusiontables.query().sql("SELECT RowID, 'Area Name', Notes, Number, Location FROM " + tableId +
            " Where State = 'BCS' Order by Number DESC LIMIT 100");*/
    Sql sql = fusiontables.query().sql("SELECT RowID, 'Area Name', Notes, Number, Location, State, Codes FROM " + tableId +
            " Where State = 'ID' AND 'City (nearest)' = '' Order by Number DESC LIMIT 100");

    try {
        Sqlresponse response = sql.execute();
        // System.out.println(response.toPrettyString());

        mylist = response.getRows();

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // For google-api-services-fusiontables-v1-rev1-1.7.2-beta this exception will always
        // been thrown.
        // Please see issue 545: JSON response could not be deserialized to Sqlresponse.class
        // http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/issues/detail?id=545
    }
}

private static void updateRows(String tableId) throws IOException {
    // IOException needed  ParseException
    count = 1;
    mylist.forEach((myRow) -> {
        try {
            // modify fields in table...
            //newAreaName = kt.firstpart(myRow.get(NOTES).toString()); //get Notes first sentence
            //newAreaName = newAreaName.replace("'", "''");
            //newAreaName += " X01";
            //String state = getStateFrmLoc(myRow.get(LOCATION).toString());
            //String state = "MX-BCS";
            float km;
            if ( "AK,MT,NV".contains(myRow.get(STATE).toString()) ) {
                km = 180f; // 111.85 miles
            } else {
                km = 80.5f;  // 50 miles
            }

            BigCity big = new BigCity(myRow.get(LOCATION).toString(), km);
            String cityState = big.cityName +", "+big.state;

            if (big.population < 10000f) {
                System.out.println("Skip for low population :"+myRow.get(NUMBER));
            } else {

                sqlupdate = "UPDATE " + tableId + " " +
                        "SET 'City (nearest)' = '" + cityState + "' " +
                        ",'Codes' = '" + myRow.get(CODES).toString() + ",#U1' " +
                        "WHERE ROWID = " + myRow.get(ROW_ID);
                System.out.println("[" + count + "]" + myRow.get(NUMBER) + ": " + sqlupdate);

                // do the update...
                if (!mtest) {  // if testing then don't update
                    sql_doupdate(sqlupdate);
                }
                count++;
                if ((count % 30) == 0) {
                    System.out.println("waiting 60 seconds");
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(60); //Fusion Tables allows 30 updates then must wait 1 minute.
                }
            }
            } catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    });

}
```